# Is there a library available in Python to create an encrypted "protected" excel file?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, encryption, pypi

Most libraries that I looked at seems to not support encrypting the entire workbook with a password. Is there one available which would make it possible? Preferably in PyPI repository.

Comment: Are you just trying to encrypt an arbitrary file? Or are you trying to do something specific to Excel, like the "Protect Workbook" feature?

Comment: Excel specific feature like "Protect workbook" I mentioned "encrypt" because the excel option for protecting the entire workbook instead of an individual worksheet is under the "encrypt" option in excel

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use a library like https://pypi.org/project/pyAesCrypt/ which encrypts/decrypts any file